# OpenCV: what is the difference between these 2 haar cascade data sets?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, object-detection, haar-classifier, cascade-classifier

I have seen there are 2 different Haar Cascade datasets in OpenCV. For an example, take a look at `haarcascade_upperbody.xml` and `haarcascade_mcs_upperbody.xml`. what is this new `mcs` thing? The only difference I can monitor is that `haarcascade_mcs_upperbody.xml` is providing a way better results than the other one.

So, can someone please explain me the difference between these 2 types? When training my own datasets, how can I select between these 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this web site have the answer : [OpenCV](http://answers.opencv.org/question/39437/opencv-what-is-the-difference-between-these-2-haar/)

The diference is eepending on there train data, so that, if you want to select a suit classifier, I prefer you try both two to find a better result.